# Implode:Invalid arguments in an array?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, arrays

I have an array in my js file.And after the user selects his prefered seats,the data creation in the array is done.

[image: selection of seats,and data creation in the array]

Then I send it to a php file for displaying.The javascript code is shown below.

```js
$('#btnsubmit').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var seat = [], item;
    $.each($('#place li.' + settings.selectingSeatCss + ' a'), function (index, value) {
        item = $(this).attr('title');                   
        seat.push(item);                
    });
    var bookseats = seat;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'confirm.php',
      data: {'bookseats': bookseats}
    }).then(function(data) {
      alert(data);
      window.location='confirm.php';
    },function(err){
      alert('error');
    });
```

When sending this data,I've made an alert(data) function to see if the values are passed correctly.Below is a screenshot of the alert.[image: alert]

The alert clearly shows us that the array has been passed to the php page.But in my php page,no data of the array is displayed.And it shows an error saying "Invalid Arguments".

[image: PHP display]

Here is my php code.

```
$bookseats = "";

if(isset($_POST['bookseats']))
    {
        $bookseats = $_POST["bookseats"];       
    }

print_r($bookseats);

$seatar = implode(',', $bookseats);
echo 'Booked Seats : '.$seatar.'<br>'.'<br>';
```

And when I try to save this array in a database,the following error is shown.[image: Database insertion error]

Here is the php code for data insertion to the database.

```
$bookings_added = $conn->query($sql);
$last_bid = $conn->insert_id;
for($i = 0; $i < count($bookseats); $i++){
    $SQL_project_has_type = "INSERT INTO bookseat (seat, bid)
        VALUES({$bookseats[$i]}, ".$last_bid.")";
    $bs = $conn->query($SQL_project_has_type);

    if($bs === FALSE) exit("mysql error: ".$conn->error);
}
```

Is there something wrong in my array?Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML I added a hidden input to hold values of chosen seats.

In js code, added a statement that sets the value for the added hidden input.

Also on successful ajax, the form is submitted in POST method along with the new values using `jquery` submit trigger.

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST" id="bookseatform" action="confirm.php">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="bookseats"/>
<div align="center"><input type="Submit" id="btnsubmit" value="Submit" /></div>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
 $('#btnsubmit').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var seat = [], item;
    $.each($('#place li.' + settings.selectingSeatCss + ' a'), function (index, value) {
        item = $(this).attr('title');                   
        seat.push(item);                
    });
    var bookseats = seat;
    $('input[name="bookseats"]').val(seat);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'confirm.php',
      data: {'bookseats': bookseats}
    }).then(function(data) {
      //alert(data);
      $('#bookseatform').trigger('submit');
    },function(err){
      alert('error');
    });
 });
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['bookseats'])){
    $bookseats = $_POST["bookseats"];   

    if(is_array($bookseats)){
        print_r($bookseats);
        $seatar = implode(',', $bookseats);
    }
    else {
        $seatar = $bookseats;
    }
}

echo 'Booked Seats : '.$seatar.'<br>'.'<br>';
```

Comment: Yes to confirm.php

Comment: If you don't need the ajax part of the js code, this - https://pastebin.com/T9MRt2tg - is fine alternative too.

Comment: :o :o :o :o :o :o

Comment: FYI, you can avoid the `is_array` conditional and force the data type to array like this: `$seatar = implode(',', (array)$bookseats);`  Effectively, if the value is a string, the string becomes the lone indexed element of the new array.  ...but from what I see I would be expecting an array.